# List with extra column

Tags: html, css

(I'm sorry for my bad English)

I have a multi-level list with a description column (see example below)
[image: Normal view]

This works well, but if the description has to be on multiple lines, the texts are overlaying on the content below the long description.

[image: Long text]

Are there any ways to solve this? If a description needs multiple lines, I want the lines below to move down, so the description fits without overwriting any text.

(The reason that I use a list, is because I use [Template:Tree_list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Tree_list) from wikipedia)

**Edit**: [See here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Magol/tree_test) for an example of Wikipedia:

See below for the source code:

```css
.description {
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<li><span class="content">row1</span><span class="description">Description1</span></li>
<li><span class="content">row2</span><span class="description">Description2.  The description can be long, and need to be on multiple lines. bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla</span></li>
<li><span class="content">row3</span><span class="description">Description3</span>
  <ul>
    <li><span class="content">row3.1</span><span class="description">Description3.1</span></li>
    <li><span class="content">row3.2</span><span class="description">Description3.2</span>
  </ul>
  <li><span class="content">row4</span><span class="description">Description4</span></li>
  </ul>
```

**Edit**

I have done some experiments, and have coming up with this (I have borrow the CSS for the "Tree list" from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MediaWiki:Common.css).
I getting closer to a perfect solution, but it stil have some issues.

- The description column is not perfect aligned. What is wrong in the calculation och the width?
- The html code is complex, can I make it cleaner?
- Can I in any way get ride of the `<div class="line">`?

Se code at https://jsfiddle.net/n7t5kaLu/

```css
.treeview .row {
  display: flex;
}

.treeview li .left {
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.treeview li li .left {
  width: calc(200px - 20px - 0.3em);
}

.treeview li li li .left {
  width: calc(200px - 40px - 0.6em);
}

.treeview li li li li .left {
  width: calc(200px - 60px - 0.9em);
}

.treeview li li li li li .left {
  width: calc(200px - 80px - 1.2em);
}

.right {
  width: 100%;
  text-indent: 0;
}

.treeview ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.treeview li {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  list-style-image: none;
}

.treeview .line {
  background: url(//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f2/Treeview-grey-line.png) no-repeat 0 -3px;
  height: 100%
}

.treeview li li {
  background: url(//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f2/Treeview-grey-line.png) no-repeat 0 -2981px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  text-indent: 0.3em;
}

.treeview li li.lastline {
  background-position: 0 -5971px
}

.treeview li.emptyline > ul {
  margin-left: -1px
}

.treeview li.emptyline > ul > li:first-child {
  background-position: 0 9px
}
```

```html
<div class="treeview">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="left">
          root
          <div class="line"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
          - Description
        </div>
      </div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="left">
              row 1
              <div class="line"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="right">
              - Description XXXXKJXLKXJKJXLKJXLKJX LKXJXL K J X L K X J K X J X L A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z Å Ä Ö
            </div>
          </div>
          <ul>
            <li class="lastline">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="left">
                  row 1.1
                  <div class="line"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="right">
                  - Description XXXXKJXLKXJKJXLKJXLKJX LKXJXLKJXLKXJ KXJXL
                </div>
              </div>
              <ul>
                <li class="lastline">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="left">
                      row1.1.1
                      <div class="line"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="right">
                      - Description kföljlkdsj fjfskjf kjflksf
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <ul>
                    <li class="lastline">
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="left">
                          row1.1.1.1
                          <div class="line"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="right">
                          - Description kföljlkdsj fjfskjf kjflksf
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>

              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="lastline">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="left">
              row1XXXX
            </div>
            <div class="right">
              - DescriptionXXXXXXXX
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <!--root-->
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

When you apply `position: absolute` to an element, you remove it from the normal flow. This means that it doesn't take up any space in the layout.

That's why surrounding elements are overlapping the absolutely-positioned element (`.description`): they don't even know it exists.

Instead of `position: absolute` try `position: relative`, which doesn't remove elements from the normal flow:

```css
.description {
  position: relative;
  left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <span class="content">row1</span>
    <span class="description">Description1</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="content">row2</span>
    <span class="description">Description2.  The description can be long, and need to be on multiple lines. bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="content">row3</span>
    <span class="description">Description3</span>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <span class="content">row3.1</span>
        <span class="description">Description3.1</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="content">row3.2</span>
        <span class="description">Description3.2</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <li><span class="content">row4</span><span class="description">Description4</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: that will miss align the descriptions accordingly to the .content text

Comment: Thank you for your proposed solution and your explanation why my code did not work (although I knew the problem with position:absolute )
The problem with your proposal is that the text is not properly aligned.

Comment: How is it not properly aligned? Each description is across from the corresponding row.

Comment: @magol, I'm not entirely sure what you're after, but here's a concept you may like: https://jsfiddle.net/hr8gagoj/1/

Comment: @Michael_B At first glance, it looks great. But then I realize that you have merged both the "content" and the descriptions in the same list, and you have removed the levels in the list. Unfortunately, this does not work. See my test of your code here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Magol/tree_test

Comment: @hungerstar - Yes, vertically it is perfect align, but not horizontal.

Comment: I have done some more work on this, see the edit of my question

Comment: In terms of the right column alignment, you have `text-indent: .3em` on the left column items. Use `text-indent: -.3em` on the right sub-items to shift them into line with the right main items.

Comment: @Michael_B That do not help :-( I have put the code on https://jsfiddle.net/n7t5kaLu/